# How do I create a Cocoa GUI to edit an array of NSDate objects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nsdate, cocoa-bindings

In one app I am working on I need to let the user edit a list of dates. I have those `NSDate` objects in an array and bound that to a `NSArrayController`. I bound a `NSTableColumn` (the only column in a table view) to that array controller using the key path `arrangedObjects.self`. This works fine - I get all the dates displayed in the table just the way I want it and I can add and remove dates.

The trouble is I can not edit the dates in the table. If I try I get an exception telling me, that `NSDate` is not key-value-coding compliant to the key `self`, which of course is true, there is no `setSelf:` method.

I have two ideas how I could solve this:

1. have my array not store `NSDate` directly but put it in an `NSMutableDictionary` or some other object first.
2. not allow the user to edit the date directly but have him remove the wrong one and re-add the corrected date.

I don’t really like both solutions. I don’t like the first because I have to put stuff in my model just to get the GUI right. And the second is not very user-friendly.

So does anyone have an idea if there is a third and even better way to solve this?

#### Update: Temporary solution

For now I am using the table view’s data source to deal with this instead of using bindings. But I’d still like to see if there is a better solution using bindings for that problem, since I don’t really want to write a data source every time this (or a similar problem) turns up. It happens not just with `NSDate` but all other value type classes provided by cocoa, even if they are mutable (like `NSMutableString`).

Answer (score 1):

***Updated***

It seems that, since NSDate has no properties you can set (as with NSNumber), in order to "edit a date" you have to replace the "old" one with a newly created one. The date must be a property of some other object or part of a container like an NSDictionary for NSDateFormatter and Cocoa Bindings to do the right thing.

Apologies for the earlier noise - I always seem to learn something new when I try something I never tried before. :-)

Comment: Of course I am binding to the column, and I am using a `NSDateFormatter`. But I’ll try leaving the `self` out of the key path.

Comment: You say "of course" as if it couldn't be any other way. It can. :-) Tables themselves can be bound and people forget to use formatters. We had no way of knowing because you didn't specify in your first revision. In any case, a model key path of self is wrong. The arranged object at a given index IS itself.

Comment: Even if I am leaving out the `self` part of the key path it won’t work. After editing a date I get an error message that `__NSCFDate` is not key value coding-compliant for the key `.`

Comment: Bah. My apologies - I've never tried loading NSDate objects into an array controller's content array before. Even with a date formatter, this does not work. Your initial thought to enclose it within an NSMutableDictionary does seem to work happily with editing. I believe this is because you can't modify a date. You create a date and if you wish to change it, you replace it with another. Therefore, it must be wrapped in either something's property or thrown in a dictionary. Updating my answer to reflect this.

Comment: ( Up-voted the question because it was a fun quiz I got wrong at first. :-) )